# variation on a Hall-Littlewood function theme

Tags: combinatorics, representation-theory, symmetric-groups, symmetric-functions

Let $\lambda$ and $\mu$ be partitions of $n$. As I understand it the (transformed) *Hall-Littlewood* function $H_\mu(t)$ is
defined by the expansion

\begin{equation}
H_\mu(t) \, := \ \sum_{\lambda \, \vdash n} \, K_{\lambda \mu}(t) \, s_\lambda
\end{equation}

where $K_{\lambda \mu}(t)$ is the Kostka-Foulkes polynomial
and $s_\lambda$ is the Schur function. $H_\mu(t)$ interpolates between the Schur function
$s_\mu = H_\mu(0)$ and the homogeneous symmetric function $h_\mu = H_\mu(1)$.

**Question:** What if we "invert" the construction and define instead
$S_\mu(t)$ implicitly by

\begin{equation}
h_\mu \, = \ \sum_{\lambda \, \vdash n} \,
K_{\lambda \mu}(t) \, S_\mu(t)
\end{equation}

Is this $t$-deformed Schur function $S_\mu(t)$ considered and/or relevant in the theory of symmetric functions?

thanks, ines.